# How to hide text behind navigationBar with animation at loading

Tags: xcode, swiftui, uinavigationbar, uitextview, uiviewanimation

The code below hide a text view behind a navigationBar based on Network status and it works great. The only problem is that we see the text going to hide behind the navigation bar at the first loading of the page.

How can i fix that? I want the text view to be already hidden at the start (Y Position -20)...

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestZStackNavigationView: View {
    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
    @ObservedObject var online = NetStatus()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("NoNetworkTitle")
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                .frame(width: screenSize.width, height: 40, alignment: .center)
                .background(Color.red)
                .position(x: screenSize.width / 2, y: self.online.connected ? -20 : 20)
                .animation(.easeIn(duration: 0.5), value: self.online.connected)
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Navigation Bar Title"), displayMode:.inline)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Ok i got it!

By default 'connected' is set to false in NetStatus() class.

I set it to true and now it's working like i want.  ;-)